# How to get the content of a custom svelte store without calling update()?

Tags: svelte, store, writable

I want to call a svelte custom store function without calling the update function. It feels ugly, especially since I don't want to update anything, I just want to query the store's content and returning a result.

To simplify, I've extended the svelte custom store tutorial (https://svelte.dev/tutorial/custom-stores) with a function that checks if the current number is equal to three:

App.js

```
<script>
    import { count } from './store.js';
</script>

<h1>The count is {$count}</h1>

<button on:click={count.increment}>+</button>
<button on:click={count.decrement}>-</button>
<button on:click={count.reset}>reset</button>
<button on:click={count.three}>is it 3? (inside)</button>
```

store.js

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

function createCount() {
    const { subscribe, set, update } = writable(0);

    return {
        subscribe,
        increment: () => update(n => n + 1),
        decrement: () => update(n => n - 1),
        reset: () => set(0),
        three: () => update((n) => {
            console.log(n==3 ? 'yes' : 'no')
            return n
        })
    };
}

export const count = createCount();
```

Check the REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/e124c879a48a4d51a53851576a3ea675?version=3.59.1

Is there a way to redefine the three function without using the update function?

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't make it very clear what you really want the `three` function to do, but it seems you can achieve that with the [`get` helper](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-get) that gives you the current value of a store.

```js
const count = writable(0);
const { subscribe, set, update } = count

const three = () => get(count) == 3 ? 'yes' : 'no'
```

Be mindful however, that it will subscribe and unsubscribe immediately to your store. This means that if your store has no subscribers when this happens, it's start/stop function will be called (firing a request each time, for exemple, if your store do that)...

In the end, it looks like what you really need is a [derived store](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-derived):

```js
const three = derived(count, $count => $count == 3 ? 'yes' : 'no')
```

With a derived store, subscriptions to the different stores will naturally be managed optimally as a function of what you really use at a given time.

Comment: Thanks! I clear was thinking about the problem the wrong way. A derived store it is!